# How to combine in one loop serial numbers and null?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, linked-list

I'm busy with implementation of singly linked list and have 2 functions: `insert_back` and `insert_after`.

Here is the listing of them:

```
void insert_back(int data)
{
    node *temp1;

    temp1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp1 = head;

    while (temp1->next != NULL) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    node *temp;

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp1->next = temp; 
}

void insert_after(int pos, int data)
{
    node *temp1;

    temp1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp1 = head;

    for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;

        if (temp1 == NULL) {
            return;
        }
    }

    node *temp;

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp; 
}
```

As you can see they are almost the same and for insert back I want to write `insert_after(null, 10)`. I can solve it by adding if condition and choose one of the loops, but it's not my aim.

Is it possible somehow to use one `while` or `for` loops together for serial numbers and null?

Also I see that param `int pos` is `int`. Should I use 0 instead of null?

Comment: You're using `cout` and `malloc`.  Is this a C or a C++ program?

Comment: You should use 0 isntead of null in that case, because it is an int.  But you might actually do an insert_after(0, 10); (inserting 10 after pos 0), so I'm suggesting a different approach: insert_after(very_high_number, 10); as equivalent of insert-back.  See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unnecessarily allocate memory in the following lines.

```
temp1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp1 = head;
```

This allocated memory will leak as you overwrite the returned address in `temp1`. You just need `temp1` to walk over the list, so there is also no need to allocate any node itself. `temp1` can point to any node.

I've taken the liberty to kind of from scratch write a routine doing both things in one go. If `pos < 0` it will add the element to the end of the list, otherwise it will add it after the pos-th element, where the first element corresponds with `pos == 1`. If `pos == 0` the element is added at the start of the list.

Also a small `main` is added to test the routine. `new_node` has been added to test if memory is not exhausted.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
        struct node     * next;
        int             data;
} node;

node * head = NULL;

node * new_node(void)
{
        node * result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
        if (result == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
                exit(10);
        }
        return result;
}

void insert_after(int pos, int data)
{
        node    *walk, * prev;
        int     i;

        prev = NULL;
        walk = head;

        for (i = 0; walk != NULL && i != pos; i++)
        {
                prev = walk;
                walk = walk->next;
        }

        if (i != pos && pos > 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Location not found.\n");
                exit(9);
        }
        else
        {
                walk = new_node();
                walk->data = data;

                if (prev == NULL)
                {
                        walk->next = head;
                        head = walk;
                }
                else
                {
                        walk->next = prev->next;
                        prev->next = walk;
                }
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        int     i;
        node    * wlk;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                insert_after(-1, i);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                insert_after(3, i+10);
        }

        for (wlk = head; wlk != NULL; wlk = wlk->next)
        {
                printf("%d\n", wlk->data);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing for the end of the chain with insert_after(pos,...) anyway, you could go for:

```
void insert_after(int pos, int data)
{
    node *temp1= head;

    for (int i=1; i<pos; i++) {
        if (temp1->next==NULL) {
            if (pos==INT_MAX) 
                break;   // pos of INT_MAX means insert at end
                         // so we continue with this last item and append
            else 
                return;  // pos higher than length of chain
        }
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    ...
}
```

Or slightly more compact:

```
void insert_after(int pos, int data)
{
    node *temp1= head;

    for (int i=1; i<pos && temp1->next!=NULL; i++) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    if (temp1->next==NULL && pos!=INT_MAX) 
        return;  // pos higher than length of chain, except for 
                 // INT_MAX (for that we just want to continue)

    ...
}
```

Then you could use

```
void insert_back(int data)
{
      insert_after(INT_MAX, data);
}
```